# Start Excel Macro with parameter from PowerShell

Tags: excel, powershell, vba

I encountered a problem with the following PowerSehll code in order to start an Excel macro and pass parameters.

```
# start Excel
$excel = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application

#open file
$FilePath = 'C:\Users\{user}\Desktop\test\Macro.xlsm'
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($FilePath)

$excel.Visible = $true

#access the Application object and run a macro
$app = $excel.Application

$sourcepath = 'C:\Users\{user}\Desktop\test\FileIn.csv'
$destinationpath = 'C:\Users\{user}\Desktop\test\FileOut.xls'

$app.Run('FormatUmsatzliste',$sourcepath,$destinationpath) 
$app.Quit()
```

The code works fine and the macro gets executed and does also what it should.
However, at the end I get the following error message and I don't know why.

As I understand it, PowerShell doesn't like the parameter.
I hope you can help me.

```
PS L:\> C:\Data\Untitled1.ps1
Exception calling "Run" with "3" argument(s): "Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A9C68"
At C:\Data\Untitled1.ps1:17 char:1
+ $app.Run('FormatUmsatzliste',$sourcepath,$destinationpath)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : COMException
```

`OverloadDefinitions

System.Object Run(System.Object Macro, System.Object Arg1, System.Object Arg2, System.Object Arg3, System.Object Arg4, System.Object Arg5, System.Object Arg6, System.Object Arg7, System.Object Arg8, System.Object Arg9, System.Object Arg10, System.Object Arg11, System.Object Arg12, System.Object Arg13, System.Object Arg14, System.Object Arg15, System.Object Arg16, System.Object Arg17, System.Object Arg18, System.Object Arg19, System.Object Arg20, System.Object Arg21, System.Object Arg22, System.Object Arg23, System.Object Arg24, System.Object Arg25, System.Object Arg26, System.Object Arg27, System.Object Arg28, System.Object Arg29, System.Object Arg30)

System.Object _Application.Run(System.Object Macro, System.Object Arg1, System.Object Arg2, System.Object Arg3, System.Object Arg4, System.Object Arg5, System.Object Arg6, System.Object Arg7, System.Object Arg8, System.Object Arg9, System.Object Arg10, System.Object Arg11, System.Object Arg12, System.Object Arg13, System.Object Arg14, System.Object Arg15, System.Object Arg16, System.Object Arg17, System.Object Arg18, System.Object Arg19, System.Object Arg20, System.Object Arg21, System.Object Arg22, System.Object Arg23, System.Object Arg24, System.Object Arg25, System.Object Arg26, System.Object Arg27, System.Object Arg28, System.Object Arg29, System.Object Arg30)`

Best regards.

Comment: Check if this applies: [Drop Workbook.Close from your macro](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/910ada61-2c0c-4178-9ea2-2c7d0e8d6a5c/exception-from-hresult-0x800a9c68-processing-will-continue-to-be-done-on-the-file?forum=exceldev)

Comment: Hi Vesper, thank you very much this change solved the issue.

Comment: I've posted that as an answer so that the question won't appear to be  unanswered anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is do not use `Workbook.close` in your macro if you're starting it via Excel.Application COM object. This issue is described here in details: [HRESULT 0x800A9C68 in Excel 2010](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/910ada61-2c0c-4178-9ea2-2c7d0e8d6a5c/exception-from-hresult-0x800a9c68-processing-will-continue-to-be-done-on-the-file?forum=exceldev). The solution is remove the call to `Workbook.Close` from the macro being called like this.